# Haskell Parsec Unexpected End of Input

Tags: haskell, parsec

Here's an example of the file I'm trying to parse:

```
XX00135                   ABCDEFGHIJ RISK SOLUTIONS            PAGE NO :      7
BEG PER: 03/17/2014            CURRENT COMPANY                       03/18/2014
END PER: 03/18/2014       QA PROCESS - REJECT REPORT                   20:28:36

BATCH: 123456789 CONTRIB: 987654321 - ABCDE FGHI-SAN DIEGO
                                                    QUOTE BACK: 1A23B45C79

CODE   ACCOUNT NO           TYP COMPANY NAME         BEG DATE END DATE ERR
------ -------------------- --- -------------------- -------- -------- ---
12345  1234567890001        AB  ABCDE FGHI PRODUCTS  20140314 20140914 059


XX00135                   ABCDEFGHIJ RISK SOLUTIONS            PAGE NO :      8
BEG PER: 03/17/2014            CURRENT COMPANY                       03/18/2014
END PER: 03/18/2014       QA PROCESS - REJECT REPORT                   20:28:36

BATCH: 234567890 CONTRIB: 987654321 - ABCDE FGHI-SAN DIEGO
                                                    QUOTE BACK: 5F7A657G87

CODE   ACCOUNT NO           TYP COMPANY NAME         BEG DATE END DATE ERR
------ -------------------- --- -------------------- -------- -------- ---
12346  2345678901           AB  ABCDE FGHI PRODUCTS  20140129 20140729 059
12346  3456789012           AB  ABCDE FGHI PRODUCTS  20140317 20140917 059


XX00135                   ABCDEFGHIJ RISK SOLUTIONS            PAGE NO :      9
BEG PER: 03/17/2014            CURRENT COMPANY                       03/18/2014
END PER: 03/18/2014       QA PROCESS - REJECT REPORT                   20:28:36

BATCH: 345678901 CONTRIB: 987654321 - ABCDE FGHI-SAN DIEGO
                                                    QUOTE BACK: 6K75L8791L

CODE   ACCOUNT NO           TYP COMPANY NAME         BEG DATE END DATE ERR
------ -------------------- --- -------------------- -------- -------- ---
12346  4567890123           AB  ABCDE FGHI PRODUCTS  20140317 20140917 059
12346  4567890123           AB  ABCDE FGHI PRODUCTS  20140317 20140917 059
 NUMBER OF SETS REJECTED ARE :         13  TOTAL SETS IN BATCH:     16,940

                           *** END OF REPORT ***
```

And here is a collection of snippets from my module:

```
module XX00135 (parseFile) where

import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>), (<*))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (Line)

data Line = Line { code    :: String
                 , account :: String
                 , aType   :: String
                 , company :: String
                 , begDate :: String
                 , endDate :: String
                 , errCode :: String }

data Page = Page { periodBeginning :: String
                 , periodEnd       :: String
                 , reportDate      :: String
                 , batch           :: String
                 , contrib         :: String
                 , quoteBack       :: String
                 , lineList        :: [Line] }

data Report = Report { pages :: [Page] }


parseReportDate :: Parser String
parseReportDate =
  manyTill anyChar (string "CURRENT COMPANY") >> spaces >> count 10 anyChar

headers :: Parser String
headers =
  choice [ try (string "\n")
         , try (string "CODE   ACCOUNT NO           TYP COMPANY NAME         BEG DATE     END DATE ERR")
         , try (string "------ -------------------- --- -------------------- -------- -------- ---") ]

line :: Parser Line
line =
  Line <$> count  6 anyChar <* space
       <*> count 20 anyChar <* space
       <*> count  3 anyChar <* space
       <*> count 20 anyChar <* space
       <*> count  8 anyChar <* space
       <*> count  8 anyChar <* space
       <*> count  3 anyChar <* newline

page :: Parser Page
page =
  Page <$> (manyTill anyChar (string "BEG PER:")    >> space >> count 10 anyChar)
       <*> parseReportDate
       <*> (manyTill anyChar (string "END PER:")    >> space >> count 10 anyChar)
       <*> (manyTill anyChar (string "BATCH:")      >> space >> count  9 anyChar)
       <*> (space >> string "CONTRIB:"              >> space >> count  9 anyChar)
       <*> (manyTill anyChar (string "QUOTE BACK:") >> space >> count 10 anyChar
       <*   skipMany1 headers)
       <*> (manyTill line (twoNewLines <|> footer))

report :: Parser Report
report = Report <$> manyTill page (try footer)

twoNewLines :: Parser ()
twoNewLines = (count 2 newline) >> return ()

footer :: Parser ()
footer = (space >> string "NUMBER OF SETS REJECTED" >> manyTill anyChar (string "*** END OF REPORT ***") >> optional eof) >> return ()

parseFile :: [(String, String)] -> String -> String
parseFile errors text =
  let rs = case parse (manyTill report eof) "" text of
      ...
```

There are 115 lines in the full file. When I `cat` the file and pipe it to my haskell, I get:

```
(line 116, column 1);
unexpected end of input
expecting "BEG PER:"
```

I had it working by just ignoring the footer and anything that followed. But my full use case is to `cat` multiple files and pipe that to my haskell, meaning that I cannot just throw away the footer and everything that follows it. Once I started trying to ignore the footer instead of just throwing it away, my problems began. It's probably something simple, and I'm just confused and over-looking something obvious.

Let me know if you need more code. I do a few transformations after parsing, and I didn't want to clutter the code with unnecessary detail.

Thanks!

Comment: The parser `manyTill anyChar (string "BEG PER:")` fails when called on an empty string (which is what is left after you have reached the end of the file). The issue is with probably with `manyTill`. Maybe try `report = (Report <$> many page) >>= \x -> try footer >> return x`

Comment: Interesting! But no love--same error. Ah! But you've got me thinking in the right direction, I think. I'm saying `manyTill line eop`, expecting `eop` to be one of `footer` or `eof`; but in this case, it's both `footer` and (followed by) `eof`! Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the problem. The code is a little different, and I'm not sure what exactly solved the problem. I spent a lot of time staring at the code and making little changes here and there. I think, though, that it had to do with `cat` appending a `newline` to the file. So I changed `footer`:

```
footer = space >> string "NUMBER OF SETS REJECTED"
       >> anyChar `manyTill` (string "*** END OF REPORT ***") >> newline >> string ""
```

Now footer consumes an extra `newline` at the end of the file, and returns a string. I use `footer` in `eop` (end of page):

```
eop =
  choice [ count 2 newline
         , footer ]
```

And I use `eop` in the last line of `page`:

```
<*> line `manyTill` eop
```

`report` is now:

```
report = count 2 newline >> Report <$> many page
```

I also changed `page`. I think it was consuming `anyChar` in unexpected ways. So now I throw away the first line of each page:

```
page = firstLine >>
  Page <$> (string "BEG PER:" >> space >> count 10 anyChar)
       ...

firstLine =
  string "XX00135                   ABCDEFGHIJ RISK SOLUTIONS            PAGE NO :"
  >> spaces > many digit >> newline
```

I think that covers all the important changes I made that eventually made the parse successful. It now parses a single file from the `cat` command, as well as multiple files concatenated by the `cat` command. Yay! I love Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like page consumes footer:

```
  <*> (manyTill line (twoNewLines <|> footer))
```

And thus report does not get to consume footer:

```
report = Report <$> manyTill page (try footer)
```

Perhaps you need 'sepBy' to recognize 'twoNewLines' between your 'page' (without that last manyTill).

Comment: Thank you! That's a great point. I've made a few changes based on your suggestion. `report = Report <$> sepBy page threeNewLines`, `threeNewLines = (count 3 newline) >> return ()`, the last line of `page` is now `many1 line <* optional footer`, and the last line of `line` no longer consumes a `newline`. Now the error is different, so I can't really adjust the code and show the new error. The new error is `(line 13, column 4): unexpected "0" expecting space`. I'll keep banging my head against this. It's bound to give in at some point. lol